# Eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a reflection about a plane

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, eigenfunctions, reflection

Consider the linear transformation $T: \mathbb{R^3 \rightarrow R^3}$ given by the reflection about the plane $\textit{P}:x+2y-z=0$. In other words, $T(\textbf{v})=\textbf{v}-2\text{proj}_n\textbf{v}$, where $\textbf{n}$ is any normal vector for $\textit{P}$ and $v\in \mathbb{R^3}$.

**a)** Find the standard matrix $A= [T]$ for $T$

That was easy. I used the standard basis vectors $e_1$ and projected them on the normal as follows:

$T(\textbf{$e_1$})=\textbf{$e_1$}-2\text{proj}_n\textbf{$e_1$}$

$T(\textbf{$e_2$})=\textbf{$e_2$}-2\text{proj}_n\textbf{$e_2$}$

$T(\textbf{$e_3$})=\textbf{$e_3$}-2\text{proj}_n\textbf{$e_3$}$

I obtained the vectors $T(\textbf{$e_1$})$,$T(\textbf{$e_2$})$,$T(\textbf{$e_3$})$ which I then wrote as columns. Thus,

$A=[T]=$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
\frac{2}{3} & \frac{-2}{3} & \frac{1}{3} \\ 
\frac{-2}{3} & \frac{-1}{3} & \frac{2}{3}\\ 
\frac{1}{3} & \frac{2}{3} & \frac{2}{3}\\ 
    \end{array}
\right)
$

**b)** If $\textbf{n}$ is any normal to $\textit{P}$, find $T(n)$ use the result to find an eigenvalue of $A$

Well if I use:

$T(\textbf{$n$})=\textbf{$n$}-2\text{proj}_n\textbf{$n$}$, I get the same normal but with opposite sign (i.e. $T(\textbf{$n$})$=$-\textbf{n}$) . How is that supposed to help me find the eigen value of $A$ though?

I mean I shouldn't be finding the characteristic polynomial and such. I feel like there should be a way to approach this with only this bit of information.

**c)** If $\textbf{v}$ is any vector in the plane $P$, find $T(v)$ using the fact that $T$ is a reflection about $P$. Use the result to find another eigenvalue of $A$.

What does this mean by "using the fact that $T$ is a reflection about $P$" ? How is that supposed to help me find another eigen value?

**d)** Find eigenspaces corresponding to eigenvalues obtained in $(b)$ and $(c)$ using the fact that $T$ is refection about $P$.

Same confusion. What does it mean by "using the fact that $T$ is a reflection about $P$" ? How is that supposed to help me find the eigenspaces?

Comment: For b), why don't you accept $-1$ as an eigenvalue? For c) - Think about what a reflection does to the plane about which it reflects.

Comment: How did you determine the -1 though? Logically, it makes sense but how did you determine that?

c) I think it would just flip the coordinate's sign right? Or is that intuition wrong?

Comment: Well, you just wrote $T(n)=-n$. I looked at the little line preceding the $n$, and guessed it must be minus one.

Comment: Well the thing is wolfram alpha given me 1 as an eigen value. Not a -1.

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=eigenvalue+of+%7B%7B2%2F3,-2%2F3,1%2F3%7D,%7B-2%2F3,-1%2F3,2%2F3%7D,%7B-1%2F3,2%2F3,2%2F3%7D%7D

Comment: Yes, $1$ is also an eigenvalue and this is part c) of your homework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors algebraically, i.e. calculate the eigenvalues as the roots of the characteristic polynomial and solve a linear, homogeneous system per eigenvalue to find the corresponding eigenvector(s). Here however, they want you to use the geometrical interpretation of the reflection to find them by reasoning.

The basic question you should ask yourself is:

*When reflecting about a plane, which vectors are mapped to a vector parallel with the vector you reflected; i.e. to a scalar multiple of that vector?*

You should try to picture this geometrically. The different sub-questions  guide you through this.

> **b)** If $\textbf{n}$ is any normal to $\textit{P}$, find $T(n)$ use the result to find an eigenvalue of $A$

Take any normal to $P$ and find its reflection: you expect to find the opposite vector as a result, right? This means any normal $\bf n$ is reflected to the vector $\bf -n$. So any normal $\bf n$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue...

You can try it out with a few normals such as $(1,2,-1)$ or $(-2,-4,2)$.

> **c)** If $\textbf{v}$ is any vector in the plane $P$, find $T(v)$ using the fact that $T$ is a reflection about $P$. Use the result to find another eigenvalue of $A$.

If you take a vector lying *in the plane*, what do you expect will happen when you calculate its reflection with respect to that plane? It remains unchanged! This means any vector $\bf p$ in the plane is reflected to the vector $\bf p$ itself, so any vector in the plane is an eigenvector with eigenvalue...

> **d)** Find eigenspaces corresponding to eigenvalues obtained in $(b)$ and $(c)$ using the fact that $T$ is refection about $P$.

With the reasoning in parts (b) and (c), you should ask yourself how many eigenvectors you can find in that situation:

- a normal to the plane is not unique, but all normals are... so you only have 1 linearly indepedent one;
- how many  linearly independent vectors lying *in the plane* can you find?

Comment: b) I mean intuitively, I feel like the eigen value should just be -1. I am just not sure how to reason it out... Is it because that an eigen value shuld satisfy $\textbf{A}v=\lambda v$ ? So if I want the two normals to be equal to each other, $\lambda$ must equal 1?

c) Well I feel like I would get another vector with opposite coordinates but I am not sure...

Comment: @FutureMathperson You are right: you expect to find $-1$ in that case because the vector is mapped to its opposite vector. An eigenvector satisfies $\textbf{A}v=\lambda v$ and through reasoning, you find that for a normal $\bf n$, you have $T(\bf n)=- \bf n$ so... ($v = \bf n$ and $\lambda = -1$).

Comment: I see you corrected the matrix so I'll delete that part of my answer.

Comment: Yes sorry. I forgot to mention that part. 

Wolfram alpha tells me that the other two eigenvectors are both equal to 1.  I'm trying to reason out why though? I feel like reflecting a vector would reverse the sign somehow...

Comment: Have you read through my answer? Most vectors you reflect are not mapped to a vector parallel to the initial vector, but to _some other vector_. However, there are a few special cases: consider vectors _normal_ to the plane (part b) and vectors _lying in the plane_ (part c). After reflection, they end up being b) _flipped_, c) _unchanged_ - you see?

Comment: @FutureMathperson I added a bit more detail in my answer.

Comment: Ohh! I see. So the eigen value would just be 1 because any point on the plane would end up mapping to itself so to find a scalar multiple, the eigen value would simply be 1.

Comment: @FutureMathperson Indeed, for part c! So the _**only** vectors_ which are mapped to scalar multiples (parallel to itself) after reflection about a plane are _normal vectors_ ($\lambda = -1$; part b) and vectors _in the plane_ ($\lambda = 1$; part c).

Comment: For part d, there is only 1 possible normal to a plane so there is only 1 linearly vector one there. Since I am spanning $\mathbb{R^3}$, would I have 3 linearly independent vectors in total?

Comment: Yes: 1 for the normal and since a plane is two-dimensional, 2 in the plane; makes 3 in total.

Comment: How would that help with the eigenspace though? As far as I know, the eigenspace is space generated by the eigenvectors corresponding to the same eigenvalue. Wouldn't the eigen space just be $\text{span{-1,1,1}}$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56483/discussion-between-stacktd-and-future-math-person).